# Delete the alpha channel from a video with ffmepg

Tags: ffmpeg

I will like remove the alpha channel of a mov file and create a new video, I prefer a copy version not transcodification.

It is posible? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not possible without transcoding, at least with ffmpeg. And likely, not possible at all.